# Computed property whose value results from an API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

An API call (Firebase) determines the return value of my `computed property` and hence whether I display certain elements in my template.

Yet, my `computed property` is actually not reactive: its value in my template doesn't change upon the API call. Why not?

JS:

```
myComputedProperty: function() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Template:

```
<span v-if="userConnected">
  User connected
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your return value isn't the return value for your computed property. It's the return value of the callback function.

You should be using `data()` and `created()` or `mounted()` to check this instead:

```
data () {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: false
    };

},
created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        this.isAuthenticated = !!user
    });
}
```